# Can I send delayed_job an in-memory only ActiveRecord object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, delayed-job

So I had some emails that didn't go out due to a mailing service API key not being instantiated.  However, *Detail* model objects were preserved in the database.  I don't want to re-create these in the database.

I wrote a rake task to send out the emails and it was easier to try and create some temporary in-memory objects rather than try to find the correct ActiveRecord objects based on what is in detail_params.  Then I send out the emails using *DetailMailerJob* and pass in the instantiated *Detail* object.

```
  temp_obj = Detail.new(detail_params)
  DetailMailerJob.new.delay.notify_job(temp_obj)
```

But I'm noticing the following error in the Delayed::Job.all queue after running the rake task:

```
last_error: "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
```

Does this mean the only way for me to pass in a *Detail* object into *DetailMailerJob* is to first find the instantiated record in the database?  (i.e., no in-memory objects)

EDIT: Here is the DetailMailer & DetailMailerJob class.

```
    class DetailMailerJob
      def notify_job(detail)
         DetailMailer.notify_job(detail).deliver 
      end 
    end


class DetailMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def notify_job(detail)
    @detail = detail
    @emailed_to = detail.emailed_to.join(", ")
    mail(to: detail.emailed_to, subject: "#{detail.full_name} - New Message") 
  end
end
```

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question without knowing what's in `DetailMailerJob`. That's what's generating the error!

Comment: Thanks for the kind advice Gene.  Updated.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this, too. It's an optimization of DJ to use already saved versions of subclasses of `ActiveRecord::Base` rather than persisting the full contents again in the DJ queue. I'm sure they do this because instances of AR can be large.

If you define a new class with the same fields of interest as `Detail` but *not* inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base`, .  Something like:

```
class DetailAsAPlainOldRubyObject
  attr_accessor :field_a, :field_b, ...

  def initialize(params)
    self.field_a = params['field_a']
    self.field_b = params['field_b']
    ...
  end
end
```

Now start the job with an instance:

```
temp_obj = DetailAsAPlainOldRubyObject.new(detail_params)
DetailMailerJob.new.delay.notify_job(temp_obj)
```

**More details:** Delayed job - in particular the method `delay` - works by storing the class of `self` (in your example `DetailMailerJob`), the name of the method (`notify_job`), and a serialized representation of the argument in a database table. Worker processes dequeue records from the table, deserialize the argument, and call the method on the class.

The problem is the serialization.  DJ augments YAML with a special [serializer for ActiveRecord](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/master/lib/delayed/serialization/active_record.rb) that encodes only the table name and primary key. Deserializing results in a `find` on the table. I suppose they're doing this to save database space and time. Of course this trick only works if the `ActiveRecord` has been saved. (IMO it would be cool if DJ skipped the tricky serialization if the record hasn't been saved, but alas it doesn't.)

Note your error message in the code at the link above! It's used in the exception raised when the `find` fails.

By using a plain object with no `ActiveRecord` base, you ought to get normal YAML serialization to a string.